# how to one product two types tax include?

Tags: product, create, taxes

How to one product two types tax (VAT and CST) include on order edit page - admin panel.

Actually I have one product add on **VAT** and **CST** tax but admin panel not showing on two type taxes.

Answer (score 0):

To add **cst and vat in 1 rule** i.e. if you want that : 1. cst for all other states of india 2. vat for your origin state eg. Karnataka

Then do as told below:

1. In Sales->Tax->Manage Tax Zones & Rates, add 2 taxes 1 with name : cst and 1 with name: vat. Select the state as * for CST and state as Karnataka for VAT. Set same priority for both the tax rates for eg. priority : 0.
2. Then in Sales->Tax->Manage Tax Rules. Create a rule and select both CST and VAT in that rule and save the rule.

Magento will automatically apply any 1 of CST or VAT according to the state specified in the address (as per tax configuration setting for applying tax based on either of: shipping origin/shipping address/billing address)